# Klaviyo Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkbox

I want to check this checkbox 'checked' => true nothing change. How can I check this automatically? Please help.

```
    public function afterProcess(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $processor, $jsLayout)
{
    if ($this->_klaviyoScopeSetting->getConsentAtCheckoutSMSIsActive())
    {
        $smsConsentCheckbox = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/checkbox',
                'options' => [],
                'id' => 'kl_sms_consent',
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.kl_sms_consent',
            'label' => $this->_klaviyoScopeSetting->getConsentAtCheckoutSMSConsentLabelText(),
            'description' => $this->_klaviyoScopeSetting->getConsentAtCheckoutSMSConsentText(),
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'visible' => true,
```

> 'checked' => false,

```
            'validation' => [],
            'sortOrder' => $this->_klaviyoScopeSetting->getConsentAtCheckoutSMSConsentSortOrder(),
            'id' => 'kl_sms_consent',
        ];

        $address = $this->_getDefaultAddressIfSetForCustomer();

        if (!$address)
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['kl_sms_consent'] = $smsConsentCheckbox;
        else {

            // extra un-editable field with saved phone number to display to logged in users with default address set
            $smsConsentTelephone = [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                'config' =>
                    [
                        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
                    ],
                'label' => 'Phone Number',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'sortOrder' => '120',
                'disabled' => true,
                'visible' => true,
                'value' => $address->getTelephone()
            ];

            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['before-form']['children']['kl_sms_phone_number'] = $smsConsentTelephone;
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['before-form']['children']['kl_sms_consent'] = $smsConsentCheckbox;
        }
    } return $jsLayout;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know it is illegal per federal law if you text these customers with marketing material. I'm not sure but it might be legal if it's order information.

You need to create a custom extension to override that function and add the line:

```
'value' => 'checked', // add this to make the checkbox checked by default
```

I have included the code for the di.xml file and the plugin file below.

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="custom-checkout" disabled="true" />
        <plugin name="imk-klaviyo-custom-checkout" type="Imk\KlaviyoOverride\Plugin\CheckoutLayoutPlugin" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

CheckoutLayoutPlugin.php

```
<?php

namespace Imk\KlaviyoOverride\Plugin;

use Klaviyo\Reclaim\Helper\ScopeSetting;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;


class CheckoutLayoutPlugin
{
public function __construct(
    ScopeSetting $klaviyoScopeSetting,
    Session $customerSession,
    CustomerFactory $customerFactory
) {
    $this->_klaviyoScopeSetting = $klaviyoScopeSetting;
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
}

/**
 * Checks if logged in user has a default address set, if not returns false.
 *
 * @return Magento\Customer\Model\Address|false
 */
public function _getDefaultAddressIfSetForCustomer()
{
    $address = false;
    if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        $customerData = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getData();
        $customerId = $customerData["entity_id"];
        $customer = $this->_customerFactory->create()->load($customerId);
        $address = $customer->getDefaultShippingAddress();
    }
    return $address;
}

public function afterProcess(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $processor, $jsLayout)
{
    if ($this->_klaviyoScopeSetting->getConsentAtCheckoutSMSIsActive())
    {
        $smsConsentCheckbox = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/checkbox',
                'options' => [],
                'id' => 'kl_sms_consent',
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.kl_sms_consent',
            'label' => $this->_klaviyoScopeSetting->getConsentAtCheckoutSMSConsentLabelText(),
            'description' => $this->_klaviyoScopeSetting->getConsentAtCheckoutSMSConsentText(),
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'visible' => true,
            'checked' => true,
            'value' => 'checked', // add this to make the checkbox checked by default
            'validation' => [],
            'sortOrder' => $this->_klaviyoScopeSetting->getConsentAtCheckoutSMSConsentSortOrder(),
            'id' => 'kl_sms_consent',
        ];

        $address = $this->_getDefaultAddressIfSetForCustomer();

        if (!$address)
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['kl_sms_consent'] = $smsConsentCheckbox;
        else {

            // extra un-editable field with saved phone number to display to logged in users with default address set
            $smsConsentTelephone = [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                'config' =>
                    [
                        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
                    ],
                'label' => 'Phone Number',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'sortOrder' => '120',
                'disabled' => true,
                'visible' => true,
                'value' => $address->getTelephone()
            ];

            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['before-form']['children']['kl_sms_phone_number'] = $smsConsentTelephone;
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['before-form']['children']['kl_sms_consent'] = $smsConsentCheckbox;
        }
    }

    if (!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn() && $this->_klaviyoScopeSetting->getConsentAtCheckoutEmailIsActive())
    {
        $emailConsentCheckbox = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/checkbox',
                'options' => [],
                'id' => 'kl_email_consent',
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.kl_email_consent',
            'description' => $this->_klaviyoScopeSetting->getConsentAtCheckoutEmailText(),
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'visible' => true,
            'checked' => true,
            'value' => 'checked', // add this to make the checkbox checked by default
            'validation' => [],
            'sortOrder' => $this->_klaviyoScopeSetting->getConsentAtCheckoutEmailSortOrder(),
            'id' => 'kl_email_consent',
        ];

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['kl_email_consent'] = $emailConsentCheckbox;
    }


    return $jsLayout;
}
}
```